# PyArrow : how to concatenate two columns into a new one ? (multi index handling)

Tags: python, multi-index, pyarrow

So, I've been using pyarrow recently, and I need to use it for something I've already done in dask / pandas : I have this multi index dataframe, and I need to drop the duplicates from this index, and select rows based on their index to replace them.

To handle the multi index, I want to concatenate my two index columns into another column, that I can use just like an index. That's what I did with dask, and it worked...

How to concatenate two columns into a new one with pyarrow ?

My dataframe looks like this :

```py
table1 = pa.table({'num1': [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5],
                   'date': [2017-4, 2018-6, 2017-4, 2018-9, 2016-7, 2018-6],
                   'data': ["some-data", "other-stuff", Null, Null, "data", "data", Null]})

table2 = pa.table({'num1': [2, 3, 5],
                   'date': [ 2018-6, 2017-4, 2018-9],
                   'data': ["new-data", "data that was missing", "data"]})
```

I need to concatenate num1 and date. I have already tried the `concat_arrays` function, but it adds the second array's elements in the end, so, not what I want.

I also tried that :

```py
a = lct.select(["num1"])
b = lct.select(["date"])

lst = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        lst.append(str(a[i][j]) + str(b[i][j]))
```

I know that pyarrow types are immutables, so I wanted to create a list that I would transform to an array later, and iterate over the arrays I've got to concatenate the data together.
But there are a few problems :

- first, it takes time.
- Then, retrieving something with the index here is a bit more complicated, it throws an `IndexError` (index out of bounds) for the `a[i]`.

I have also thought about concatenating the two dataframes with `concat_tables` and sorting what I needed and what I didn't need, but I still have the same problem : how do I select data using **two** columns ?

I also tried joining the two dataframes together, I wanted to join the dataframes on the key columns and then drop the useless data.

```py
table_valid = table1.join(table2, keys=['num1', 'date'], join_type="left anti")
```

I intended to use several join types to see what worked, but I can't do any join because keys can't have null type. And I have some keys that have somme null values in them, I guess. So, knowing that, I wanted to drop the null values from the keys :

```
iter1 = pc.drop_null(table1["num1"])
iter2 = pc.drop_null(iter1["date"])

table_valid = iter2.join(table2, keys=['num1', 'date'], join_type="left anti")
```

This could have been a good idea, but trying to join iter2 to table2, I got the following error : `'pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray' object has no attribute 'join'`

I know I could just be doing all of this with pandas, but I really want to do it with pyarrow and really have no clue how...

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to concatenate two columns horizontally, as string, you can do that:

```
import pyarrow.compute as pc

pc.binary_join_element_wise(
    pc.cast(table1['num1'], pa.string()),
    pc.cast(table1['date'], pa.string()),
    "-"
)
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with column projection by chance? I want to read a dataset and create a "month_id" column which is the year and month of a timestamp column in the data. roughly like this (error though):

pc.binary_join_element_wise(
    pc.year(ds.field("interval_timestamp_utc")).cast(pa.string()),
    pc.month(ds.field("interval_timestamp_utc")).cast(pa.string()),
    ""
)

Comment: Best to use strftime for this https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.strftime.html